# Sending JSON object from PHP to Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post

PHP file named page.php

```
<?php
$php_variable = $_GET['param1'];
$uv = str_replace("{ZIP Code}", $php_variable,'http://iaspub.epa.gov/enviro/efservice/getEnvirofactsUVDAILY/ZIP/{ZIP Code}/JSON');
$homepage = file_get_contents($uv);
echo $homepage;
?>
```

homepage stores the json object that contains three fields
I would like to print out those three fields in my html file. I have created a ajax function to print out the fields on the web page.

```
<form action="../getuv.php">
    <select name="param1" onchange="this.form.submit()">
        <option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
        <option value="92507">92507</option>
        <option value="30078">30078</option>
        <option value="92606">92606</option>
        <option value="30004">30004</option>
        <option value="32034">32034</option>
        <option value="37160">37160</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script>
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "page.php", 
 success: function (data) { 
  console.log(data);
  var obj = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "UV INDEX" + "<br>" + "Zip code: " + obj[0].ZIP_CODE + "<br>"; 
 } 
}); 
</script>
```

Nothing gets printed out. Also, at the moment, I got to the php page and stay there. I would like to return back to my original html page.

I do send param1. Param1 is a zip code value that the user chooses from a drop down menu.

Comment: Instead of `echo $homepage;` use `echo json_encode($homepage);`. The format will be JSON and `jQuery.parseJSON( data )` will no longer be required.

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's console?

Comment: @machineaddict If I read it right, he's fetching JSON so no encode is necessary

Comment: @Machavity: My bad, now I see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that the form is added, it is clear what the problem is: You make an ajax call on page load, without any parameters, and when you make a change to your `select`, you submit the form the *old-fashioned way*, without using ajax. This causes a page reload where your ajax call is fired again, again without any parameters.

What you need to do is:

1. Load your form but without the `onhange` handler;
2. Do not fire the ajax call on page load;
3. Instead, add an event handler for when the `select` is changed, set the correct data type and send the data you need to send.

The end result would look something like:

```
<form action="">
    <select name="param1">
        <option value="">Choose a zipcode </option>
        <option value="92507">92507</option>
        <option value="30078">30078</option>
        <option value="92606">92606</option>
        <option value="30004">30004</option>
        <option value="32034">32034</option>
        <option value="37160">37160</option>
    </select>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('select').on('change', function(event) {
  // Make sure the form does not get submitted the old-fashioned way
  event.preventDefault();

  // Your ajax call, including the parameter, data type and method
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",                    // GET to match your php script
    url: "page.php",
    dataType: 'json',               // Let jQuery parse the results   
    data: $('form').serialize(),    // Send you data
    success: function (obj) { 
      console.log(obj);             // this will be an object for valid json
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "UV INDEX" + "<br>" + "Zip code: " + obj[0].ZIP_CODE + "<br>"; 
    } 
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

Comment: So if I remove the onchage handler, once I click on the drop down menu it will come to the function above? Also, what do you mean by don't fire the ajax call on page load? as in don't call it? but you did in the code provided above. Also, there is a syntax error with serialize. I am fairly new to all this. So I am still googling all of this. Thanks.

Comment: @Ria I am calling it inside an event handler, when something happens. You are calling it simply when you open the page. And yes, there was a typo, the line should have finished with a comma (same with `dataType`), I have edited the answer. Note that I have also put the script in a document ready handler.

Comment: there is also a missing parenthesis somewhere in there. but thanks for the explanation

Comment: @Ria Yes, I think there was missing something almost at the end, but these are just details. Did you manage to solve your problem?

Comment: @jeoren Not yet. I have to go to class. I will try again in the evening.

Answer (score 2):

this shoulde be

```
$php_variable = $_POST['param1'];
```

because you use method post in ajax

```
 type: "POST",
 url: "page.php",
```

Comment: param1 must be a GET because I supply it to the php script

Answer (score 2):

You don't seem to be sending a `param1` to the script.

```
<script>
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "page.php",
 data: {param1: $("select[name='param1']").val()},
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (obj) { 
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "UV INDEX" + obj[0].UV_INDEX + "<br>" + "Zip code: " + obj[0].ZIP_CODE + "<br>"; 
 } 
}); 
</script>
```

Try this one. It should work.

Comment: I do. I just didn't show it. param1 is the zip code that the user clicks from a drop down menu.

Comment: What do your browser receive from `page.php` then? Are you receiving any errors, or a 500 status code?

Comment: @Ria you need to show how you are sending param1, because the code above does not show it, so it is hard to figure out what could be wrong if you are not showing us the whole code.

Comment: page.php opens up a url and receives a json object.

Comment: I know what page.php does, but according to your javascript code the page.php is not receiving a param1. You have to put it in like i have shown you in the code. If you do that it should work. Try the code I have supplied, and it should work without a hitch.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I do supply param1. I have posted the code that shows how I am sending over param1 to page.php

Comment: @Ria the code you are displaying is not sending param1 to page.php, I have edited the code in my example, so that it should be working.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo $homepage;
```

and in your JS Script

```
    $.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: "page.php",
     data: {
             param1: 'some value'
            }, 
     success: function (data) { 
      console.log(data);
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "UV INDEX" + "<br>" + "Zip code: " + data[0].ZIP_CODE + "<br>"; 
     } 
    });
```

Comment: What happens when I am getting param1 from a drop down menu? How to store that value in 'some value'?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Header

you can use this

```
 <?php 
$reponse = "what you need";
print(json_encode(['reponse' => $reponse])); 
?>
```